# Android addView setting TextView textColor to white?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a button which calls this function to add a View to my main layout:

```
private void createWrkHist() {
    View addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addWrkHist);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) addBtn.getLayoutParams();
    int aboveID = params.getRule(BELOW);

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.work_history_table, null);
    ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainForm);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams insertParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    insertParams.addRule(BELOW, aboveID);
    v.setLayoutParams(insertParams);
    mainView.addView(v);
    params.addRule(BELOW, R.id.wrkHist);
    addBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

The layout is being added because I used some code to try and focus on a `EditText` on the added View and it worked. However, all the `TextViews` in the added View is completely white. How do I set the style/theme of the View I am adding to default? This is the XML of the layout I am adding:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/wrkHist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Position:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/wrkPosition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="15" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Company:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/wrkCompany"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="15" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Start Date:"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="15">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/wrkStartDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:inputType="date" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text="End Date:"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/wrkEndDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Duties:"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/wrkDuties"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:lines="5" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Application's context to create the inflater because it will try to use application's theme.

Use Activity's context instead, or use container's context that will give you Activity's context too.

```
private void createWrkHist() {
    View addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addWrkHist);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) addBtn.getLayoutParams();
    int aboveID = params.getRule(BELOW);

    ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainForm);

    LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(mainView.getContext());
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.work_history_table, mainView, true);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams insertParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    insertParams.addRule(BELOW, aboveID);
    v.setLayoutParams(insertParams);
    mainView.addView(v);
    params.addRule(BELOW, R.id.wrkHist);
    addBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```